# Set size and location of image in printpreview c#

Tags: c#, print-preview

i already can print a image into the printpreview, but when i click print preview, the image was too big. How do i resize it in printpreview? Here is the screenshot and also the code:

Here is the code:

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb1.Image, 0, 0);
```

i put that code in printpreview function. So when i click printpreview, this function will run. And here is the result:

Here is the screenshot of the printpreview:

[image]

how do i resize it? the image was too big

Comment: You should not be doing this, only display what actually gets printed on paper.  In other words, that DrawImage() call belongs in your PrintDocument.PrintPage event handler.  It now has the wrong size because you are not using the PrintPreviewControl.Zoom property.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of just pointing to the location of the image, you can instruct graphics to print the image into a certain area by defining a rectangle which can have a defined width/height.

```
e.Graphics.DrawImage(pb1.Image, new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height));
```